# Create database and add data during application installation

Tags: database, windows, winforms, installation, installation-package

I have developed a windows form application. I have also created a database on sql server and added data to this database.

Now i want to install this application at clients place. I want to know the ways to move my created database on client's location. How can i do this during application installation? If i have to include database scripts in installation file and run it.how can i do it? If its a long process please specify links which helps me in accomplishing this task.

Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [GDR R2 database project](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14258) (part of Visual Studio).

You can use this to reverese engineer your existing database into scripts within  a Database project, and place under source code control. You can synchronise existing and deploy fresh databases from this project.

- [Visual Studio 2010 SQL Server Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491.aspx)
- [An Overview of Database Build and Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833165.aspx)
- [Visual Studio Database Guide](http://vsdatabaseguide.codeplex.com/)

You can also use commercial tools such as those sold by RedGate.